# formatting affidavit with multiple pages

Tags: notaries

I know how to write a one-page affidavit, at least for some situations. How do I prepare a multipage affidavit in the U.S.? In other words, what's different because it has multiple pages?

This is not for immediate or online submission to a court or for an already-named case in any forum and there may not be a caption, but an already-notarized paper affidavit might be needed later as evidence. I want to prepare the affidavit properly before notarization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top of an affidavit and the closing of an affidavit are the same if it is one page long, or many pages long (a simple form I use where I practice is below, although some places expect something slightly more elaborate). In a multi-page affidavit it would be customary to have page numbers and to number each paragraph sequentially, but there is really nothing else that is different. It isn't required to initial each page, but it wouldn't be uncommon for an affiant to do so to avoid efforts to falsify pages before the last one.

Thus:

AFFIDAVIT OF JOHN DOE

STATE OF ILLINOIS  )

```
                 ) ss.
```

COUNTY OF PODUNK   )

I, John Doe, the Affiant, being duly sworn, state that the following statements are true to the best of my knowledge and belief.

1. I am 93 years old.
2. . . . .
3. . . . .

. . .

143. The UFO conspiracy then paid me $666.00 in pennies under the Eiffel Tower.
144. Further affiant sayeth not.

X_______________________

John Doe

Sworn before me this 3rd day of June, 2019 by John Doe. Witness my hand and my official seal. My commission expires: _________________.

X _____________________

Notary Public

Address:

```
                  [SEAL]
```

The most common standards for court documents in the U.S. (although there is not one uniform set of standards) is 8.5" by 11" paper (taller top to bottom than it is wide); Times New Roman, Arial or Courier 12 point font; double spaced; one sided; half inch side margins and one inch top and bottom margins; left justified or fully justified; black ink typewritten portions on a white background and no highlighting, with handwritten portions in blue ink with a ballpoint pen. Some courts require recycled paper. If it is going to sit around for decades, use acid free paper or it will turn yellow and become brittle. Sometimes the heading is typeset rather than typed, but that usually isn't necessary. The current practice is to disfavor embossed seals as they don't scan and photocopy well.

Comment: You did a good job for typing on here, but most in Illinois quote the civil code at the bottom.

Comment: @Putvi In this case, it sounds like the person asking the question doesn't know which jurisdiction the affidavit will ultimately be used in, or precisely the purpose for which it will be used. A reference to an Illinois Code section isn't very helpful if the case ends up in an Alabama court.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. I didn't mean it as a complaint and am sorry if you took it that way. I just was saying some counties will get nitpicky.

Comment: @Putvi It is always better to prepare documents when you know when and where they will be used. More generally, most people don't realize that affidavits are not usually admissible evidence at trial in court cases, because they are hearsay. So, they may not be achieving the objectives that they think that they will when they prepare an affidavit.

Comment: That's true, but at least in IL they are used when people do not or can not show up for court.

Comment: @Putvi Very skeptical of that claim in any circumstance where the rules of evidence apply. Pretty much the primary purpose of the hearsay rule is to prevent trial by affidavit. There are exceptions to the rule (e.g. for matters related to real estate title, business records, statements of a party-opponent, motions for summary judgment, preliminary matters), but affidavits are not admissible in evidence simply because someone can not or does not show up for court.

Comment: It is probably different in federal court, but in Illinois, Supreme Court Rule 414 allows for the taking of written depositions when the evidence may not be available for a hearing or trial. In written form, the answers would be an affidavit. You are right that it is not not the preferred form, but it is done from time to time.

Comment: The difference between a written deposition and an affidavit is that cross-examination, after a fashion, is permitted in the case of a written deposition. See, e.g. https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_31 Testimony that has been subject to cross-examination in the same case or a case with the same incentives for the parties taking the testimony an defending the case, unlike an affidavit is not hearsay and is admissible in evidence.

Comment: In federal court yes, but I meant in IL.

Comment: @Putvi Written depositions in Illinois as in federal court, allow for cross-examination. See Illinois Rule 210(a). http://www.illinoiscourts.gov/SupremeCourt/Rules/Art_II/ArtII.htm#210

Comment: Yes, I have seen that rule and you are right about it. There a certain circumstances outlined in court cases where statements outside of court are admissible though. People v. Prather in IL and https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-foster-58?resultsNav=false

Comment: Useful. Near home, rules seem nonspecific but I didn't seek case law. I often prepare an affidavit to record my personal knowledge of an event contemporaneously with the event, for which any other evidence may be weaker; it may not be needed for years. I try to keep to one page and format accordingly but perhaps should reconsider. For fonts, my word processor on Linux has none of them; Garamond is generally the most readable variable-pitch font and I have the similar DejaVu Serif.

Comment: Colorado Rule of Civil Procedure 10 provides the formatting requirements in the Colorado's state trial courts. http://www.jdporterlaw.com/legal-authority/colorado-rules-civil-procedure/ (the appellate courts require 14 point font because the judges are older and read more of the day which is harder on their eyes).

Answer (score 0):

Some courts have rules on the paper, font, and other things, you should use, but as long as you sign it in front of a court official or notary and put the correct heading on it to file it, you should be fine.

In many states, you E-File now, so most modern court documents wouldn't really be viewed in terms of pages. You wan't what you right to be correct, not just the page to look a certain way, as long as it is notarized and has the header of your case.

Comment: I am not downvoting this, but "*paper, font, and other things*" has nothing to do with the legal relevance of an affidavit, and it hardly addresses the OP's question. Strict formalities/specs on "*paper, font, and other things*" only take place when briefing in the SCOTUS and perhaps few other places, but not for commonplace matters such as an affidavit. Also, you seem to assume that the OP's affidavit is for some court proceeding, but affidavits also are used in matters that are **not** court proceedings and where e-filing is not even implemented.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I like in a town of 10k people and the local court here has rules on paper etc. I have also worked in the Indiana court system and they had a set of rules on such. I am not saying they will enforce it to the letter at each step, but normally there are rules in place even outside the Supreme Court.

Comment: I added to the opening post. Also, in the answer, "wan't" and "right" probably should be "want" and "write", respectively. I'll consider using court rules as a guide.